# Trouble with webscraping Amazon Prices

Tags: python, web-scraping, anaconda

I am trying to create a python script that would notify me via email when an Amazon price drops using BeautifulSoup. My problem is that when testing if the code works by putting converted_price set greater that the price, I still do not get an email.

The script gives me no errors when I run it. I have tried to reinstall Anaconda/Python, change Amazon URLS, looked into the documentation of smtplib, and looked through StackOverFlow for previously solved attempts.

I am NOT using this for an illegal purpose. I just want to learn how to webscrape.

I am using this man's tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY

I have

```
  import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import smtplib

    URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Sony-Full-Frame-Mirrorless-Digital-Camera/dp/B00FRDUZXM'

    headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4101.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/83.0.474.0'}

    def check_price():
        page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
        price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
        converted_price = float(price[0.5])

        if(converted_price < 1.700):
            send_mail()

        print(converted_price)
        print(title.strip())

    def send_mail():
        server = smtplib.SMTB('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()

        server.login('email@gmail.com', 'app password')

        subject = 'Price fell down!'
        body = 'check amazon!!!'

        msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

        server.sendmail(
            'email@gmail.com',
            msg
        )
        print('HEY EMAIL SENT. ')

        server.quit()

        check_price()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different HTML parser. I haven't tested this but I think it's the solution. The selenium library has a html parser or you could use the html.parser library. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am a beginner to Python. I have no idea where to start

Comment: @JimmySlimmy try reading [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) about the html parser library, then replace this:  ```soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')``` with this ```soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, myvar)``` (myvar is the variable that contains the result of your parsed html)